# Bind jquery hover events to mobile click events

Tags: jquery, events, onclick, mouseevent

I have a lot of hover events on lots of different places on a site.To be specific they're all `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` functions.Now when viewed on a mobile device click events or `touch` events (i think they're called) triggers the `mouseenter` ,but not the `mouseleave` ,how do i trigger the other part of the function ? .That's one part of the problem.

here's how a typical function looks like :

```
function hover() {
  $('#my_div).mouseenter(fucntion(){
    $('my_selector#1',$this).show();
  }).mouseleave(function(){
    $('my_selector#1',$this).hide();
  });
}
hover();
```

The other part is  ,that on some places where there are `mouse-enter-leave` events there are also `click` events. ( example : `mouseenter` a button is shown [example above] which you can then click on).
When viewed on mobile devices, a `touch` event fires both `mouseenter` and `click` the same time.How can i solve this so that one `touch` fires the `mouseenter` then anothor `touch` triggers the `click` ?

example of click :

```
function click() {
  $('#my_div my_selector#1').click(function(){
    //something happens
  });
click();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say, for the first case, there's no "great" solution.
If the hovering content blocks other important content, the mobile design should be alterede to make the hovering work better.

For the second case, you could use element visibility to toggle, what the click should do.

For instance:

```
function hover() {
    if($('element').is(':visiblie')){
        click();
    }else{
        $('element').show();
    }
}

function click(){
    doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Upvote for not suggesting agent detection and offering a practicable solution :)